# In “die Bohnen fünf Minuten kochen lassen”, is “die Bohnen” the object of “lassen” or “kochen”?

Tags: sentence-structure, accusative-and-infinitive

**Question**

Each question relates to the German sentence just above it.  I hope these apparently five questions are merely asking the same question five times.

> 1. die Bohnen fünf Minuten kochen lassen

Is *die Bohnen* the object of *kochen* or *lassen*?

> 2. Ich lasse mich nicht belügen.

Is *mich* the object of *belügen* (in which case it is an indirect reciprocal) or of *lasse* (in which case a direct reciprocal)?

> 3. Auch einer der Männer, die neben dem Wagen gingen, hatte sich abhängen lassen und ging jetzt auf einer Höhe mit mir.

Is *sich* the object of *abhängen* or *lassen*?

> 4. sich einen Bart/die Haare wachsen lassen

Is *sich* the dative complement (or indirect object) of *wachsen* (someone allows: the beard growing to himself) or the dative complement of *lassen* (someone allows to himself: the beard growing)?

> 5. Man fragte ihn von Rechtswegen, was er [Candide] lieber wolle:  sechsunddreißigmal durch das ganze Regiment Spießruten laufen oder sich auf einmal zwölf bleierne Kugeln durchs Hirn jagen lassen.

Is *sich* the dative complement of *jagen* (Candide allows: someone’s driving bullets into his brain) or the dative complement of *lassen* (Candide allows to himself: bullets being driven into the brain)?

**Background**

To answer the question, you don't have to read this background or any postscript.

In English, we may have *letting someone come* or *letting someone cook the beans* but not *letting cook the beans*.  We might however hear, *Well, let it cook for five minutes*, in which case *cook* suddenly becomes intransitive with the same meaning as *be cooked* (in which *cooked* is transitive).

But not every English verb will accommodate this switching.  For example, we would not say *Let Tom call* in the sense of *Tom rufen lassen*. (I am assuming that *Tom rufen lassen* is having someone call Tom.  *Letting Tom call* will always mean letting Tom call someone else.)

So I am wondering which of the following is the case:

(a) In German, any typically transitive verb can become implicitly passive and thus intransitive in a *lassen* context.  In *die Bohnen fünf Minuten kochen lassen*, for example, a German speaker will see *letting the beans cook (be cooked) for five minutes* (which has essentially the same structure as *ihn kommen lassen*).  Likewise, in *ihn rufen lassen*, a German speaker will see *letting him be called*.

(b) In German, we allow *lassen* to take an infinitive with only an object (patient) but no subject (agent).  In *die Bohnen fünf Minuten kochen lassen*, therefore, a German speaker sees *letting an unspecified agent cook the beans for five minutes* (or *allowing the cooking of the beans*).  In *ihn rufen lassen*, he or she would see *letting an unspecified agent call him* (or *allowing the calling of him*).

Note:  By speaking of “what a German speaker sees” I am not trying to confine meaning to psychology. I will be equally happy to receive native speaker intuition or any other relevant support for (a) or (b).  (For instance there might be evidence by analogy to another language in which the direct and the indirect reciprocals look different.)  Of course, if neither is right, please let me know what is.

**P.S.**

I am realizing that 4 might actually have these many potential syntactic analyses because a question arises not only in respect of *sich* but also of *Bart*.

(a1) lassen[sich, Bart] wachsen[-, -] (allow to himself a beard's growing)

*wachsen* is passive and intransitive.  *sich* is the dative complement of *lassen*. *Bart* is the accusative object of *lassen* but the agent of *wachsen*.

(a2) lassen[-, Bart] wachsen[sich, -] (allow a beard's growing to himself)

*wachsen* is passive and intransitive. *sich* is the dative complement of *wachsen*. *Bart* is the accusative object of *lassen* but the agent of *wachsen*.

(b1) lassen[-, -] wachsen[sich, Bart] (allow growing a beard to himself)

*wachsen* is active and transitive. *sich* is the dative complement of *wachsen*. *Bart* is the accusative object of *wachsen*. (*wachsen* does not have an express agent.)

(b2) lassen[sich, -] wachsen[-, Bart] (allow to hisemlf growing a beard)

*wachsen* is active and transitive. *sich* is, however, a dative complement of *lassen*. *Bart* is the accusative object of *wachsen*. (Again, *wachsen* does not have an express agent.)

(<strike>b3</strike>) lassen[-, sich] wachsen[-, Bart] (allow himself growing a beard)

*wachsen* is active and transitive. *sich* is the accusative object of *lassen* and the agent of *wachsen*. *Bart* is the accusative object of *wachsen*. (I guess in this case we don't know whose beard we are talking about.  Someone might have permitted himself the silly hobby of tending a goat's beard. Therefore, (b3) cannot be what a German speaker "sees" in a typical instance of *sich einen Bart wachsen lassen*.)

**P.S.2**

Why did I reverse *the beans* and *cook* to create an example of something not used in English, i.e. *letting cook the beans*?

I see in the comments section that at least three people have had this question.  If you are having this question, it means indeed you have not grasp the very thing under consideration. So, well you might ask.

Very quickly, *letting cook the beans* is meant to be a schematic representation of a syntactic structure not used with English *let*, but common for German *lassen*, namely:

> A<sup>LET</sup> + *let* + [null] + infinitive + P<sup>INF</sup>     :     e.g. you let [null] do it

where A<sup>LET</sup> is the agent (subject) of *let*, and P<sup>INF</sup> is the patient (object) of the infinitive.

One catch is that, because of the ordinary inversion of verb and object in a dependent context, German would have this surface structure:

> A<sup>LET</sup> + *lassen (lässt)* + [null] + P<sup>INF</sup> + infinitive

An example of German in this structure is:

> ihn rufen lassen

when this means *having him summoned*.

That it could have some other meaning not relevant to the topic (e.g. *having him summon another*) need not detain anyone.

Comment: @addy2012 Do you not see the difference between (a) and (b)? If (a), we have a single syntactic form but the infinitive (e.g. of cook or kochen) switches between active and passive in meaning. If (b), the verb is always in the active, but we get two syntactic structures. As you say, it is a question that can arise in English as well (only in English the answer is clearly (a)).

Comment: *ihn rufen lassen* can mean both "allow him to call" as well as "Have someone call him"

Comment: "Lass ihn (doch) seine Oma rufen" can either mean "He should call his grandma" but also "Allow him to call his grandma". It's really context. Usually you can *hear* the difference. It has a very different tone to mean "allow" than "have him"

Comment: so "Lass ihn rufen" can mean:

-"have someone call him"
-"allow him to shout"
-"make him shout"

Comment: "lassen" has so many different meanings: http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/verb-lassen/

Comment: @addy2012 Just so you may rest easy, let me say that I wholeheartedly accept that *ihn rufen lassen* can also mean *having him shout*. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, really a complex issue. I have a half-finished answer that I will complete and submit at a later time, I have to leave now.

Comment: There is a reason why the grammatical element *predicate* is not called *verb*. You have just found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some Indo-European languages, there's a construction called [Accusative and Infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_and_infinitive) (abbreviation AcI, *Accusativus cum infinitivo*). In this construction, the accusative object of the main verb also serves as subject of a dependent clause, and in some languages (e.g. Latin), if this object is a pronoun, the reflexive form is obligatory.

So, to answer your questions:

**I. Does the accusative object in the example sentences belong to the main verb *lassen*, or to the dependent verb?**

Let's see if we can change the sentences to include accusative objects for both verbs:

> 1. Sie lässt **den Mann** die Bohnen fünf Minuten kochen.
> 2. Sie lässt **den Mann** **sie** nicht belügen.
> 3. Sie lässt **den Mann** sich vom Wagen abhängen.
> 4. Sie lässt **den Mann** sich die Haare wachsen.
> 5. Sie lässt **den Mann** sich zwölf Kugeln durchs Hirn jagen.

So you can see that in all sentences, the object of *lassen* is missing in the originals, and the objects that are present all belong to the dependent verbs.

**II. Does *lassen* make the dependent verb passive?**

In German, *lassen* certainly implies a passiv-ish mood. Among the English translations of *lassen* there's also *leave*, so they idea is that some other action happens without the main subject actually doing anything.

As you have seen, it's true that the direct object of *lassen* can be implicit. However, I wouldn't go as far as to say that this changes the dependent verb into the passive form, or a transitive verb into an intransitive one (on a grammatical level as opposed to expressing a mood).

Reflexive pronouns in general also can make an action "passiv-ish", even though grammatically it is not. So there's (semantically) a continuum between active and passive. This may be connected to the fact that e.g. in Latin, the reflexive pronouns are always used for the AcI.

I also really couldn't distinguish between (a) "leave the beans alone so they cook" and (b) "letting an unspecified agent cook the beans". These are really two sides of the same thing, which is expressed by *lassen*.

**III. How to analyze "sich den Bart wachsen lassen"?**

Just like in example sentence (2), *sich* can in principle be both be the accusative object of *lassen* and the dative object of *wachsen*. So it's ambigous, or both, and I don't think trying to distinguish transitivity or intransitivity helps. Additionally, sometimes a reflexive construction is halfway between transitive and intransitive anyway, so it's complicated enough even without *lassen*.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why, in section I, 2 would come out any different than the others. The object present in the original, i.e. *mich* (which has become the second *sie* in your re-write), would be that of the dependent verb *belügen*.  The (accusative) object of *lassen* is the one you supplied, i.e. *den Mann*. Therefore, 2 is no different than the others, and the (accusative) object of *lassen* and that of *belügen* are **not** identical. No?

Comment: The "idea is that some other action happens without the main subject actually doing anything." - I don't think we are talking about the same thing. Suppose we *let Caesar conquer the world*. Yes, some action (the conquest) happens without *our* doing anything further; so that may be "passivity" in your sense. But that doesn't taint the verb *conquer* with any implicit passivity in the grammatical sense (as happens when we *let the beans cook for five minutes*).

Comment: That you cannot distinguishing between (a) and (b). This is very informative. My question (obviously) tries to make sense of the behavior of infinitives in the *lassen* context with no more than ordinary grammatical concepts pertaining to verbs in any event (such as active vs. passive voice, subject and object). But native German speaking minds (I presume you're one) may have recourse to grammatical categories peculiar to the *lassen* context; hence the resistance to a reductionist account.

Comment: @Catomic: I was trying to say that in principle you cannot distinguish if "mich" is the object of "lassen" or the object of "belügen". So it's not obvious that "mich" has become the second "sie". But you are right, OTOH "belügen" is always transitive, so some object is needed, and OTOH the one doing the lying cannot be "sie" herself, so in this case, it also must be the object of belügen. I'll edit the answer. There are examples like "ich lasse mich gehen" where the dependent verb is intransitive, so "mich" *must* be the object of lassen (resp. the subject of the dependent clause).

Comment: @Catomic: I'm indeed not sure if we are talking about the same thing. *We let Caesar conquer the world* could either be translated as "Wir **lassen** es **zu**, dass Cäsar die Welt erorbert" (we allow through inactivity that Caesar conquers it) or as "Wir lassen Cäsar die Welt erobern" (that can has both the above meaning and "we told Cäsar he should conquer the world, and now we sit back and watch while he does it"). Yes, neither does taint the verb with any implict grammatical passivity. But"wir lassen die Bohnen kochen" doesn't taint "kochen" was passivity, either.

Comment: (continued) "Die Bohnen kochen" is a perfectly fine sentence, "kochen" can be both transitive and intransitive. So I don't really understand where you see any implicit passivity (grammatically, not with respect to the mood).

Comment: Thanks for these further clarifications. I realize that I have not manage to get the sense of passivity I had in mind across. Let me think about the best way of trying to do it.

Comment: @Catomic: Another thought: You can analyze "Ich lasse die Bohnen kochen" in two ways: "Ich lasse (ihn) die Bohnen kochen" -> "Er kocht die Bohnen", "die Bohnen" is the acc. **object**. That would be similar to your interpretation (b). Or, "Ich lasse die Bohnen kochen" -> "Die Bohnen kochen", "die Bohnen" is the **subject** of the dependent clause. That would be similar to your interpretation (a). And the switch from object/transitive verb to subject/intransitive verb might what you'd see as "passive".

Comment: (Continued). In German, you cannot really distinguish both interpretations, except by meaning (and sometimes the meaning isn't really different, as in this case). In English, you need SVO order, so I suppose "I let the beans cook" wouldn't be confused with "I let him cook the beans" by a native speaker. So is it that you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am talking about.  I actually wrote a whole ANSWER as a means of trying to bring out the sense of "passivity" I had in mind; but you anticipated me. I believe we reach similar conclusions. I think I'll let it (my 'answer') stand; you can look at it if you like. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

Based on the responses so far it seems to me that the answer is "neither (a) nor (b)" insofar as interpretation is conceived of as a matter of "what happens in the mind of a native speaker."

**Background**

In English, we have basically these two forms which *let + infinitive* may take, where A stands for agent and P for patient.

> A<sup>LET</sup> + *let* + P<sup>LET</sup>/A<sup>INF</sup> + infinitive + P<sup>INF</sup>     :     e.g. you let me do it
>
> A<sup>LET</sup> + *let* + P<sup>LET</sup>/A<sup>INF</sup> + infinitive + [null]     :     e.g. you let me come [null]

What we don't have in English is the following.

> A<sup>LET</sup> + *let* + [null] + infinitive + P<sup>INF</sup>     :     e.g. you let [null] do it

But German allows what is equivalent to this third form, for example:

> Herr Green empfing sie sehr eilig, als sei vieles einzuholen, nahm Herrn Pollunders Arm und schob Karl und Klara vor sich in das Speisezimmer, das besonders infolge der Blumen auf dem Tische, die sich aus Streifen frischen Laubes halb aufrichteten, sehr festlich aussah und doppelt die **Anwesenheit** des störenden Herrn Green **bedauern** ließ. (From Der Verschollene by Kafka.)

--where *Anwesenheit* is the patent of *bedauern*, but we have nothing to serve as the patient of *ließ* as well as the agent of *bedauern*.

Another example is:

> ihn rufen lassen

but only if you take the meaning of this expression that helps to set up the question, i.e. *having him summoned*, instead of some other meaning that has nothing to do with the price of tea in China.

Looking at this third form, I believe a beginning student of German coming over from English has two strategies available to him (in a reverse order to the presentation in the main question).

(b) Simply accept that German has a third form (not found in English); that German speakers use *lassen* to mean what in English would be *letting the calling of him* and *letting the regretting of someone's presence* without expressly specifying who is to do the calling or regretting.

(a) Or alternatively do a mental trick to change the voice of the infinitive from active to passive so you see *letting him be called* and *letting the presence be regretted*.

Part of my question was to ask whether German speakers adopted either of these strategies.  But I seem to be finding out that the "third form" is so natural to a German speaking mind that no strategy of any kind is necessary--even to the extent that the question does not even register.

Comment: As a student of German, (b) was covered on the most part by equating it to the construction "have/get sth. done [by so.]" (have the car fixed, get one's hair done, etc.), though admittedly, German is far more extreme in its *Genauigkeit* when it comes to specifying an extraneous agent: *"einen Drachen steigen lassen"*, comes to mind. As for (a), this seems no different to me than replacing *lassen* with *allow* or as a friendly imperative, "let us pray", "let's go", etc. One form for which I did not find a similar structure in English is "etw. lässt sich [gut] + Infinitiv".

Comment: @user19407 I cannot understand your comments unless I assume you have (a) and (b) backwards. So assuming, yes, (a) and (b) are meant to be "obvious" strategies; so they should be familiar to you. As for *etw. lässt sich [gut] + Infinitiv* it has an exact analogue in English if *sich* is the patient of *lassen* and agent of the infinitive; alternatively, if *sich* is the patient of the infinitive, the sentence is simply an instance of the "third form" I am talking about. The presence of the reflexive does not make it a new structure.

Comment: Yes, that looks similar to what I thought. And no, native Germans need neither of these strategies. It is often the case when two languages employ different constructs, to the non-native speaker it looks like there must be a "strategy" to wrap his head around this usage. For example, English has another AcI construction "I want him to do s.th.", but you need to replace that with a subclause in German "Ich möchte, dass er etwas tut". So when I learned English, I mentally replaced constructions like these until I got used to it, and now I can think directly in that way.

Comment: BTW, the Latin AcI is much more similar to the German AcI (after all, Latin doesn't have fixed SVO order like English), and when I learned Latin in school, I never had any problems understanding these constructions directly, without the need for any strategies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all your questions is very simple. German has a complex predicate. You first combine the verbs into a predicate, and then you add the complements. The complements count as complements to the complex predicate, not to any single verb. This, at least, is the structure of the German clause (in contrast to the structure of English). At the meaning level, you can still try to figure out to which of the verbs the complement relates more closely.

Therefore, the German case is also different from the classical AcI construction. Latin AcI may involve a verb that embeds a clause with an accusative subject and an infinitival verb. The German structure involves only one clausal level.

For details: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koh%C3%A4rente_Konstruktion